# Convert haskell function to prolog error

Tags: haskell, prolog

i'm trying to convert this haskell function

```
llenaPares _ [] = []
llenaPares (a,b) ((c,d):ys)
      | a < c     = (a,b) : llenaPares (a+1,b) ((c,d):ys)
      | otherwise = (c,d) : llenaPares (c+1,d) ys
```

Basically this function takes a list of tuples as argument, for example,

```
[(1, 8), (5, 0), (6, 4), (10, 0), (11, 10), (12, 0)]
```

and return a list from 0 to max(x) of list with each tuple pair if exists or the previous value. For example

```
[(1,3),(3,5),(7,9),(12,0)] will return [(0,0),(1,3),(2,3),(3,5),(4,5),(5,5),(6x9),(7,9),(8,9),(9,9),(10,9),(11,0)]
```

Im doing this in prolog

```
llenaPares(A,B,[], RES).
llenaPares(A,B,[c(C,D)|YS], RES) :-
        A < C,
        append([c(A,B)], RES, SOL),
        sum(A,1,SIG),
        llenaPares(SIG,B,[c(C,D)|YS],SOL).
llenaPares(A,B,[c(C,D)|YS], RES) :-
     C>=A,
     append([c(C,D)], RES, SOL),
     sum(C,1,SIG),
     llenaPares(SIG,D,YS, SOL).

sum(A,B,C):-C is A+B.
```

But doesn't work.
What's wrong?

```
?-
|    llenaPares(0,0,[c(1,8),c(5,0),c(6,4),c(10,0),c(11,10),c(12,0)], SAL).
   Call: (7) llenaPares(0, 0, [c(1, 8), c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], _G4798) ? creep
   Call: (8) 0<1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) 0<1 ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:append([c(0, 0)], _G4798, _G4922) ? creep
   Exit: (8) lists:append([c(0, 0)], _G4798, [c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (8) sum(0, 1, _G4925) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G4926 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (8) sum(0, 1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (8) llenaPares(1, 0, [c(1, 8), c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (9) 1<1 ? creep
   Fail: (9) 1<1 ? creep
   Redo: (8) llenaPares(1, 0, [c(1, 8), c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (9) 1>=1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1>=1 ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:append([c(1, 8)], [c(0, 0)|_G4798], _G4940) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:append([c(1, 8)], [c(0, 0)|_G4798], [c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (9) sum(1, 1, _G4943) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G4944 is 1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 2 is 1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) sum(1, 1, 2) ? creep
   Call: (9) llenaPares(2, _G4945, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (10) 2<5 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 2<5 ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:append([c(2, _G4941)], [c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], _G4952) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:append([c(2, _G4941)], [c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], [c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (10) sum(2, 1, _G4955) ? creep
   Call: (11) _G4956 is 2+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 3 is 2+1 ? creep
   Exit: (10) sum(2, 1, 3) ? creep
   Call: (10) llenaPares(3, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (11) 3<5 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 3<5 ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:append([c(3, _G4941)], [c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], _G4970) ? creep
   Exit: (11) lists:append([c(3, _G4941)], [c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], [c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (11) sum(3, 1, _G4973) ? creep
   Call: (12) _G4974 is 3+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 4 is 3+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) sum(3, 1, 4) ? creep
   Call: (11) llenaPares(4, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (12) 4<5 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 4<5 ? creep
   Call: (12) lists:append([c(4, _G4941)], [c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], _G4988) ? creep
   Exit: (12) lists:append([c(4, _G4941)], [c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], [c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (12) sum(4, 1, _G4991) ? creep
   Call: (13) _G4992 is 4+1 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 5 is 4+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) sum(4, 1, 5) ? creep
   Call: (12) llenaPares(5, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 5<5 ? creep
   Fail: (13) 5<5 ? creep
   Redo: (12) llenaPares(5, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (13) 5>=5 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 5>=5 ? creep
   Call: (13) lists:append([c(5, 0)], [c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], _G5006) ? creep
   Exit: (13) lists:append([c(5, 0)], [c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], [c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (13) sum(5, 1, _G5009) ? creep
   Call: (14) _G5010 is 5+1 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 6 is 5+1 ? creep
   Exit: (13) sum(5, 1, 6) ? creep
   Call: (13) llenaPares(6, _G5011, [c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (14) 6<6 ? creep
   Fail: (14) 6<6 ? creep
   Redo: (13) llenaPares(6, _G5011, [c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (14) 6>=6 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 6>=6 ? creep
   Call: (14) lists:append([c(6, 4)], [c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], _G5018) ? creep
   Exit: (14) lists:append([c(6, 4)], [c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798], [c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (14) sum(6, 1, _G5021) ? creep
   Call: (15) _G5022 is 6+1 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 7 is 6+1 ? creep
   Exit: (14) sum(6, 1, 7) ? creep
   Call: (14) llenaPares(7, _G5023, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Call: (15) 7<10 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 7<10 ? creep
   Call: (15) lists:append([c(7, _G5019)], [c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(..., ...)|...], _G5030) ? creep
   Exit: (15) lists:append([c(7, _G5019)], [c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(..., ...)|...], [c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (15) sum(7, 1, _G5033) ? creep
   Call: (16) _G5034 is 7+1 ? creep
   Exit: (16) 8 is 7+1 ? creep
   Exit: (15) sum(7, 1, 8) ? creep
   Call: (15) llenaPares(8, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (16) 8<10 ? creep
   Exit: (16) 8<10 ? creep
   Call: (16) lists:append([c(8, _G5019)], [c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...], _G5048) ? creep
   Exit: (16) lists:append([c(8, _G5019)], [c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...], [c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (16) sum(8, 1, _G5051) ? creep
   Call: (17) _G5052 is 8+1 ? creep
   Exit: (17) 9 is 8+1 ? creep
   Exit: (16) sum(8, 1, 9) ? creep
   Call: (16) llenaPares(9, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (17) 9<10 ? creep
   Exit: (17) 9<10 ? creep
   Call: (17) lists:append([c(9, _G5019)], [c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...], _G5066) ? creep
   Exit: (17) lists:append([c(9, _G5019)], [c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...], [c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (17) sum(9, 1, _G5069) ? creep
   Call: (18) _G5070 is 9+1 ? creep
   Exit: (18) 10 is 9+1 ? creep
   Exit: (17) sum(9, 1, 10) ? creep
   Call: (17) llenaPares(10, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (18) 10<10 ? creep
   Fail: (18) 10<10 ? creep
   Redo: (17) llenaPares(10, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (18) 10>=10 ? creep
   Exit: (18) 10>=10 ? creep
   Call: (18) lists:append([c(10, 0)], [c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...], _G5084) ? creep
   Exit: (18) lists:append([c(10, 0)], [c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...], [c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (18) sum(10, 1, _G5087) ? creep
   Call: (19) _G5088 is 10+1 ? creep
   Exit: (19) 11 is 10+1 ? creep
   Exit: (18) sum(10, 1, 11) ? creep
   Call: (18) llenaPares(11, _G5089, [c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (19) 11<11 ? creep
   Fail: (19) 11<11 ? creep
   Redo: (18) llenaPares(11, _G5089, [c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (19) 11>=11 ? creep
   Exit: (19) 11>=11 ? creep
   Call: (19) lists:append([c(11, 10)], [c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(..., ...)|...], _G5096) ? creep
   Exit: (19) lists:append([c(11, 10)], [c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(..., ...)|...], [c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (19) sum(11, 1, _G5099) ? creep
   Call: (20) _G5100 is 11+1 ? creep
   Exit: (20) 12 is 11+1 ? creep
   Exit: (19) sum(11, 1, 12) ? creep
   Call: (19) llenaPares(12, _G5101, [c(12, 0)], [c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (20) 12<12 ? creep
   Fail: (20) 12<12 ? creep
   Redo: (19) llenaPares(12, _G5101, [c(12, 0)], [c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (20) 12>=12 ? creep
   Exit: (20) 12>=12 ? creep
   Call: (20) lists:append([c(12, 0)], [c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(..., ...)|...], _G5108) ? creep
   Exit: (20) lists:append([c(12, 0)], [c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(..., ...)|...], [c(12, 0), c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Call: (20) sum(12, 1, _G5111) ? creep
   Call: (21) _G5112 is 12+1 ? creep
   Exit: (21) 13 is 12+1 ? creep
   Exit: (20) sum(12, 1, 13) ? creep
   Call: (20) llenaPares(13, _G5113, [], [c(12, 0), c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (20) llenaPares(13, _G5113, [], [c(12, 0), c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (19) llenaPares(12, _G5113, [c(12, 0)], [c(11, 10), c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (18) llenaPares(11, _G5113, [c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(10, 0), c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (17) llenaPares(10, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(9, _G5019), c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (16) llenaPares(9, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(8, _G5019), c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (15) llenaPares(8, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(7, _G5019), c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(..., ...)|...]) ? creep
   Exit: (14) llenaPares(7, _G5019, [c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(6, 4), c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (13) llenaPares(6, _G5113, [c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(5, 0), c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) llenaPares(5, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(4, _G4941), c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) llenaPares(4, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(3, _G4941), c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) llenaPares(3, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(2, _G4941), c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) llenaPares(2, _G4941, [c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(1, 8), c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) llenaPares(1, 0, [c(1, 8), c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], [c(0, 0)|_G4798]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) llenaPares(0, 0, [c(1, 8), c(5, 0), c(6, 4), c(10, 0), c(11, 10), c(12, 0)], _G4798) ? creep
true .
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect? Tell which goals you expect to succeed or fail.

Comment: I writed a example in my question, an input and output. I am expecting that.

Comment: Put the **concrete** goals that you tried. Otherwise this is guesswork only

Comment: I edit with my input and the result i'm having.

Comment: The trace is not helpful. But the query **is** helpful. Now say what you expect and what you get (failure/loop etc).

Comment: And: Reduce the size of your example. I am sure you can give a smaller one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Prolog is a bit rusty, but here is what I see:

```
llenaPares(A,B,[], RES).
                   ^^^^ shouldn't this be []?
```

In:

```
llenaPares(A,B,[c(C,D)|YS], RES) :-
        A < C,
        append([c(A,B)], RES, SOL),
        sum(A,1,SIG),
        llenaPares(SIG,B,[c(C,D)|YS],SOL).
```

shouldn't RES be a larger list than SOL? I think you need to swap them in the `append` call.

Finally, instead of `C >= A` (which is almost the same as `A < C`) I think you want `A >= C`.

Comment: You don't need `append/3` here at all. Simply write a goal like `Ls = [c(A,B)|Ls0]` to state that `Ls` is a list whose first element is `c(A,B)` and whose rest is `Ls0`. More generally, you never need `append/3` to *prepend known elements* to a list. Simply write them down like before, using unification directly.

Answer (score 3):

To emulate your program as faithfully as possible:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

llenaPares(_, [], []).
llenaPares((A,B), [(C,D)|Ys], [P|Ps]) :-
        A #< C,  P = (A,B), Ap #= A+1, llenaPares( (Ap,B), [(C,D)|Ys], Ps)
      ; A #>= C, P = (C,D), Cp #= C+1, llenaPares( (Cp,D), Ys, Ps).
```

This works with SICStus or SWI.  Now we can use the relation to "compute the inputs":

```
?- llenaPares(P, Ys, [(0,0),(1,8),(2,8),(3,8),(4,8),(5,0),(6,4),(7,4),(8,4),(9,4),(10,0),(11,10),(12,0)]).
   P =  (0,0), Ys = [(1,8),(5,0),(6,4),(10,0),(11,10),(12,0)]
;  P =  (0,0), Ys = [(1,8),(5,0),(6,4),(9,4),(10,0),(11,10),(12,0)]
;  P =  (0,0), Ys = [(1,8),(5,0),(6,4),(8,4),(10,0),(11,10),(12,0)]
;  ... .
```

So here the "result" is given, and we ask for all "inputs" `Ys` that
would lead to that result.

Or we may simply ask what this relation is about:

```
?- length(Ps, N), llenaPares(P, Ys, Ps).
   Ps = [], N = 0, Ys = []
;  Ps = [(_A,_B)], N = 1, P = (_C,_D), Ys = [(_A,_B)],
   _E#=_A+1, _A#=<_C, _A in inf..sup, _C in inf..sup, _E in inf..sup
;  Ps = [(_A,_B),(_C,_D)], N = 2, P = (_A,_B), Ys = [(_C,_D)],
   _E#=_A+1, _F#=_C+1, _C#=<_E, _C#>=_A+1, _C in inf..sup, _A in inf..sup, _E in inf..sup,_F in inf..sup
;  ... .
```